# Pyspark dataframe SQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to convert the following statement into DF select statement:

```
Select 
 YY,
 PP,
 YYYY,
 PPPP,
 Min(ID) as MinId, 
 Max(ID) as MaxID 
from LoadTable
```

I have tried the following but it doesnt seem to be working :

```
df.select(df.ID,df.YY, df.PP,df.YYYY,df.PPPPP).agg({"ID": "max", "ID": "min"}).toPandas().to_csv(outputFile, sep="|", header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: Did you check each component of the statement? Can you provide the errors you see. You see a bunch of things that you need to consider before posting on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are performing an aggregate function, what you may be missing here is the `GROUP BY` statement.  If so, your SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT YY, PP, YYYY, PPPP, Min(ID) as MinId, Max(ID) as MaxID 
  FROM LoadTable 
 GROUP BY YY, PP, YYYY, PPPP
```

The corresponding PySpark DataFrame statement would be then

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupBy(df.YY, df.PP, df.YYYY, df.PPPP).agg(F.min(df.ID), F.max(df.ID))
```

HTH!